# PySide Qt4 widget exchange in a hboxlayout

Tags: qt4, widget, pyside

I'd like to exchange a widget inside a QHBoxLayout. This code seems to work, but as soon as I do the actual `app._exec()`, the code crashes with `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::python::error_already_set'`. Is there any way to get the actual error message? (or to resolve this problem)

```
gaParent = gameArea.parent().layout()
gaParent.removeWidget(gameArea)
gameArea = DrawingScreen()
gameArea.setObjectName("gameArea")
gaParent.insertWidget(0, gameArea)
```

Comment: and when you don't remove the `gameArea` it works? maybe a problem while updateing references... have you tried calling `gameArea.setParent(None)` call to `gameArea.destroy()` or `gameArea.deleteLater()`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a C++ guy and not so much of a Pythonist, so excuse me if this makes no sense. However, from my perspective, it looks as if gameArea.parent().layout() returns a QLayout. That object does not have the insertWidget method.

Apart from that, I'm not sure where the boost::python::error_alread_set comes from. Can you do some intelligent printf-ing to try to determine when that boost error enters the picture?

Comment: Yes - it's a QLayout, but a QHBoxLayout exactly (no casting needed here). Unfortunately I don't think I have access to anything else - there's no error before `app._exec()` and then something fails internally, so I can't catch it in any way - the whole app just exits.

Comment: what to do you use more than Qt? To my knowledge, Qt is not based on boost... (asks the non-pythonist)

Comment: e8johan: pyside interface to qt4 is generated using boost